# Open CV image quality issue

Tags: opencv

We are trying to process input image(attached-portion of image is masked becuase of sensitive data) using open cv 3.4.2-1 and getting output with full black colour. Please check attached output image . Please suggest how we can improve the quality to processed image to remove or corp the white space and get only that ID card portion of the image. Because after this,the image will be processed for OCR. Currently due to bad output image OCR failes completely.

Input image -maskes the portion of image

[image]

Output image
[image]

Comment: You should give an example image without mask (if it is an id usually there is an example image in a government page same with credit card)... it is hard to know what you are doing or how to get it better, without seeing how the card looks like. Also, you should post some of the code, to understand how did you get there....

Comment: Please find the sample input image and code to process image... input image :: 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93Vnm9ZxkpyVTVHS1ltbldSbXNIVXVUbkkyeHNmX043MnFZ/view?usp=drivesdk                         code::: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93Vnm9ZxkpyWkJIMEw5MU1Gd0xCNmpneHg5dEpxWUpGUUpF/view?usp=drivesdk